# AS3 Side Scroller Not exactly how I want it

Tags: actionscript-3

Im trying to create a side scroller game on actionscrip3.0. I have it down and everything but it's not exactly what I'm looking for. I want my character to always be in the center of the screen. (www.realmofthemadgod.com) Is a great example of what type of side scroller I want my game to be like. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet and mine is to implement a world camera, as I call it, to your game.

Each of your game objects will have two sets of coordinates. One is in relation to the game world (world coords), the other in relation to the camera (screen coords).

World coords are for everything other than displaying. So stuff like physics. Screen coords are just for displaying.

Your camera will also need a set of world coords. It doesn't need screen coords because that doesn't make any sense.

In the end your objects' screen coords will just be the differences between theirs and the camera's world coords.

For example if your object is at (100, 100) and your camera is at (90, 90) then your object will look like it's at (10, 10). Object at (200, 200) and camera at (150, 250) will end up at (50, -50).

Keep in mind the origin point of your screen coords is the top left corner of your screen by default. If you want the origin to be the center of your screen, that is an object that is right on top of the camera should appear in the center of your screen, you must add half the width and half the height of your screen to your final screen coords.